# A loop to duplicate rows based on column value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to duplicate rows if the value in `qty` column in grater than `1`. It should be duplicated the number of times the value in the cell is. I then want to copy the results in a different `sheet` and edit the `qty` column. The code below does it but the header of the `qty` column is changed. How do I fix this and make it a bit more efficient?

```
Option Explicit

Sub generateDups()
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).ClearContents
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(2).ClearContents
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(3).ClearContents
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(4).ClearContents

    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim inNum As Variant
    xRow = 1

    Do While (Cells(xRow, "A") <> "")
        inNum = Cells(xRow, "D")
        If ((inNum > 1) And IsNumeric(inNum)) Then
            Range(Cells(xRow, "A"), Cells(xRow, "D")).Copy
            Range(Cells(xRow + 1, "A"), Cells(xRow + inNum - 1, "D")).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            xRow = xRow + inNum - 1
        End If
        xRow = xRow + 1
    Loop

    copyAndEdit
End Sub



Sub copyAndEdit()
    Dim cValue As String
    Dim rowIndex As Integer
    Dim destRow As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet

    Set srcSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    destRow = 0
    
    With srcSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For rowIndex = 1 To lastRow
            cValue = .Cells(rowIndex, 2).Value
            destRow = destRow + 1
            destSheet.Cells(destRow, 1) = .Cells(rowIndex, 1)
            destSheet.Cells(destRow, 2) = .Cells(rowIndex, 2)
            destSheet.Cells(destRow, 3) = .Cells(rowIndex, 3)
            destSheet.Cells(destRow, 4) = .Cells(rowIndex, 4) 
        Next rowIndex
    End With
        
    Set srcSheet = Nothing

    With destSheet
        destRow = 0
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For rowIndex = 1 To lastRow
            destRow = destRow + 1
            If destSheet.Cells(destRow, 4).Value > 1 Then
                destSheet.Cells(destRow, 4).Value = 1
            Else
                destSheet.Cells(destRow, 4).Value = .Cells(rowIndex, 4).Value
            End If
        Next rowIndex
        
    End With
        
    Set destSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Current data:**

[image]

**What I am getting:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

Comment: Note that row counting variables need to be `Long` Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Did you debug your code to finde he issue? Go through it step by step using F8 and see where the header `Qty` gets overwritten, so you know in which part of your code the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part cause the issue since you are writing over the header in the second part of your code:

```
destRow = 0

'.....

For rowIndex = 1 To lastRow
    destRow = destRow + 1
    If destSheet.Cells(destRow, 4).Value > 1 Then
        destSheet.Cells(destRow, 4).Value = 1
```

So you set the destRow to be 0 (i.e. `destRow = 0`). In the first iteration it will be row 1 (`destRow = destRow + 1` -> `destRow = 1`). And since the cell return a value greater than 1 beacuse it's not empty or have a 0 in the cell, it will print 1 in the first row (i.e "Qty" will be overwritten).

One way (if you always going to have [numeric values](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/isnumber-isnumeric/)) is to use `Isnumeric` like this (replace this part `If destSheet.Cells(destRow, 4).Value > 1 Then`):

```
If IsNumeric(destSheet.Cells(destRow, 4).Value) > 1 Then
```

Another way is to skip the first header is by ignoring first row in iteration:

```
If destSheet.Cells(destRow, 4).Value > 1 And destRow <> 1 Then 'Could be >1 also
```

---

Side note, I would also use sheet reference on this part and also declare the sheet1:

```
Do While (srcSheet.Cells(xRow, "A") <> "")
```

Comment: seems the problem was in the `If` statement, using `If destSheet.Cells(destRow, 4).Value > 1 And destRow <> 1 Then` As you suggested seems to work.

Comment: Glad it worked out in the end! Happy coding =)!